# SQL GROUP_BY choose from non-grouped column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL Table with following columns:

```
| Key | Created_at | Acc_id |
```

SQL is running in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.

Im' trying to get, for each Acc_id, the Key that has smallest Created_at. Naturally, I would write something like

```
SELECT Key
       , MIN(Created_at)
       , Acc_id 
From MyTable 
GROUP BY Acc_id
```

But query fails, because I have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and it does not know which Key to choose from the groups. I want the one corresponding to MIN(Created_at) (the one from same row), but how do I tell it?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/

Comment: @ZhaniBaramidze please show some sample data and desired result data . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `group by`.  Use filtering.  here is an example:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.created_at = (select min(t2.created_at)
                      from mytable t2
                      where t2.acc_id = t.acc_id
                     );
```

This query will have optimal performance with an index on `mytable(acc_id, created_at)`.

Comment: in t I'm only searching with created_at? what if several rows of different acc have same?

Comment: @ZhaniBaramidze . . . I'm not sure what your concern is.  This is a *correlated* subquery, so it only returns the rows with the max `created_at` for each `acc_id`.

Comment: query never ends :D which indexes do you think are needed?

Comment: I think the query is OK but change the MAX for MIN to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM MyTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM MyTable m
  WHERE m.Acc_id = t.Acc_id AND m.Created_at < t.Created_at
)
```